# Concatenate a parameter value with prefix and postfix in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a text box which is supplied with the following expression

```
="<" & @prmLogicalFeedtype & ">"
```

Basically I want the value of single valued parameter to be prepended and appended with `<` and `>`

for example when the value of `@prmLogicalFeedtype`  is `Test`

the text box value is `<Test>`

But I am getting `[BC30201] Expression expected` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to reference parameters, then you use the following format

Usually to get the value of a parameter

```
Parameters!parametereName.Value
```

or to get the associated label

```
Parameters!parametereName.Label
```

So in your case I guess this would work.

```
="<" & Parameters!prmLogicalFeedtype.Value & ">"
```